# How to sum from two different table with different column name

Tags: mysql, sum, mysql-workbench

Im having a hard time to sum values from two different tables with different column name

Here's my table financer which has (name , bets)

```
-----------------
|Name     | Bets |
-----------------
|Example1 |115   |
```

And here's my table promoter which has the column of (name,sponsor_money)

```
--------------------------
 |Name     | sponsor_money|
--------------------------
 |Example2 |10            |
```

I tried this code

```
SELECT SUM(bets + sponsor_money) AS allmoney from financer,promoter;
```

The result is 205 instead of 125

Answer (score -1):

select SUM(f.Bets + p.sponsor_money) AS allmoney,
from financer f, promoter p;